# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null (shopping basket)?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to make a shopping basket with JSP. I´m getting the code from the first JSP (because it shows me the information that I'm getting on the statement) but then when I submit to create the arraylist it's not getting the same code that I used in the first statement. It shows the following error:

> error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>   type Informe de Excepción
>
> mensaje Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP
>   /carritobolsos.jsp en línea 23
>
> descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no
>   pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
>
> excepción
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al
>   procesar la página JSP /carritobolsos.jsp en línea 23
>
> 20:        <% 21: DriverManager.registerDriver(new
>   oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()); 22: Connection conn =
>   DriverManager.getConnection
>   ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system", "javaoracle");
>   23:         int codigo=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cod"));
>   24:          25:                 Statement
>   pstm=conn.createStatement(); 26:
>
> Stacktrace:
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>   causa raíz
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>       java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
>       java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       org.apache.jsp.carritobolsos_jsp._jspService(carritobolsos_jsp.java:132)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

JSP Code:

```
<%
            String consulta;
            int posicion;
            int numeroregistros=0;

            if(request.getParameter("posicion")!=null){
                posicion=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("posicion"));
            }else{
                posicion=1;
            }

    DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = 
                    DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system", "javaoracle");

                    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery("select cod_producto, nombre_producto, detalles, precio, imagen from (SELECT ARTICULOS.*, ROWNUM rnum FROM (SELECT cod_producto, nombre_producto, detalles, precio, imagen FROM ARTICULOS ORDER BY COD_PRODUCTO) ARTICULOS WHERE ROWNUM < "+(posicion+6)+") WHERE rnum >= "+posicion);                     
                    Statement sentencia2 = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rset2 = sentencia2.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(COD_PRODUCTO) AS NUMERO FROM ARTICULOS");
                    rset2.next();   
                    numeroregistros = rset2.getInt("NUMERO");
                    rset2.close();  

                            String producto="";   

            while(rset.next()){       
        producto+="<div class='card h-100'>";
        producto+="<a href='carritobolsos.jsp?cod="+rset.getInt("COD_PRODUCTO")+"'><img class='card-img' src='Articulos/"+rset.getString("imagen")+"'alt=''></a>";
        producto+="<div class='card-body'>";
        producto+="<h3 class='card-title'>";
        producto+="<a href='carritobolsos.jsp?cod="+rset.getInt("COD_PRODUCTO")+"'>"+rset.getString("NOMBRE_PRODUCTO")+"</a>";
        producto+="</h3>";
        producto+="<h4 style='margin: 0px;'>"+rset.getDouble("precio")+"€</h4>";
        producto+="<p class='card-text'>"+rset.getString("detalles")+"</p>";                    
        producto+="</div></div>";
                    }         

                    int next=posicion+6;
                    int prev=posicion-6;
                    producto+="<div>";
                    producto+="<ul class='pagination' style='padding: 2.5%;'>";
                    if (posicion!=1){                   
                    producto+="<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='web_NAK_articulos.jsp?posicion=" + prev + "'>Anterior</a></li>";}
                    else {
                        producto+="<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='web_NAK_articulos.jsp?posicion=" + prev + "'>Anterior</a></li>";
                    }
                   if (numeroregistros>= next){
                    producto+="<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='web_NAK_articulos.jsp?posicion=" + next + "'>Siguiente</a></li>";}
                   else {
                        producto+="<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='web_NAK_articulos.jsp?posicion=" + next + "'>Siguiente</a></li>";
                    }
                   producto+="</ul>";
                   producto+="</div>";
                    %>                               

    <%=producto%>



<%
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system", "javaoracle");       
        int codigo=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cod"));

                Statement pstm=conn.createStatement();

            String consulta="select cod_producto, nombre_producto, precio from articulos where cod_producto="+codigo+"";

                ResultSet rs=pstm.executeQuery(consulta);
                while(rs.next()){

String[] datositem = request.getParameterValues("chkarticulo");
ArrayList<String> articulos;
ArrayList<String> paginacion = new ArrayList<String>();

if (session.getAttribute("compra")==null)
{
            articulos=new ArrayList<String>();
            }else
        {

            articulos = (ArrayList<String>)session.getAttribute("compra");

            if (request.getParameter("valorfalso")!=null)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<paginacion.size();i++)
                {
                    if (articulos.indexOf(paginacion.get(i))!=-1)
                    {
                        articulos.remove(paginacion.get(i));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (datositem!=null)
        {
            for (int i=0;i<datositem.length;i++)
            {
                if (articulos.indexOf(datositem[i])==-1)
                {
                    articulos.add(datositem[i]);
                }
            }
            session.setAttribute("compra", articulos);
        }
        %>
        <form name="form1" method="get" action="carritobolsos.jsp">
        <table border="1">
        <tr><th colspan="2">Titulo</th><th>Precio</th></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <%if (articulos.indexOf(rs.getInt(1))==-1)
                {%>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chkarticulo" value="<%=rs.getInt(1)%>">
                <%}else{%>
                <intup type="checkbox" name="chkarticulo" CHECKED value="<%=rs.getInt(1)%>">
                <%}%>
            </td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%>€</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <%}%>
        <td colspan="3" align="right" style="background-color:white">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" align="right" style="background-color:white">
            <input type="submit" name="btncomprar" value="Comprar">
            <a href="vercarrito.jsp">Ver Carrito compra</a>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you put your stack trace?

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Comment: Please update your question, and put the part of `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` when trying to `parseInt` a `null` value coming from `request.getParameter("cod")`.

This is the error line:

```
 int codigo=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cod"));
```

What you must do is to handle `null` value coming from the request before parsing it into `int`, you can do it this way:

```
 int codigo=Integer.parseInt(stringtoInt(request.getParameter("cod"), 0));
```

Where `stringToInt` is a function that converts a `String` to `int` if you don't want to use an external library like `guava`.

An implementation of `stringToInt` could be like this:

```
int stringToInt(String value, int defaultValue) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(value);    
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```